# How to add clickable, expandable picture via a thumbnail on Markdown?

Tags: image, markdown, thumbnails, expand

I am trying to add an image on a page on my docusaurus website, I want to keep the photo high-def and want to show an initial thumbnail that is clickable that expands to the full-size high definition image. I have found how to link the picture to an external webpage, but I want the image to open as a function on the page the picture exists on.